# Is there such a thing as wall lights that you can plug into a power outlet?

Tags: light-fixture

There is a room in our house with a fluorescent bulbs from the dark ages and they've stopped working a while back. We've tried replacing the starter, it worked for a moment but stopped, maybe a loose connection somewhere. We can't get an electrician to come check it out for the time being, so what I'm wondering is, are there any wall lights that you can plug into a power outlet and hang on the wall? This might be a stupid idea, but is there? Googling only brought out accent lights, but I want something a little more powerful.

Comment: If you want something more powerful, you should just go for a floor lamp.  Wall sconces are going to be limited to one light, usually in the <40 watts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely: what you want are called "wall mount plug-in lamps". You have a number of choices, e.g.:[image: a handsome wall-mount light]

See that pipe going downward? It's a conduit that dresses up the extension cord and protects it from getting yanked on. At the bottom is a standard plug.

These come in all sorts of shapes and sizes. I have one in my house which takes a 3-way bulb (50/100/150W) so you can get a lot of light out of them, and they often have hinges to let you swing them in and out.

Generally you will need to drill 2 holes into your drywall, hammer in a set of drywall anchors, and then attach a plate to it. (All the parts are included in the light.)

If you're renting, check with your landlord before drilling holes in the wall--but often it's easy enough to use spackle or compound to fill the holes you made, and then paint over it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.